# c# sqldatareader no data

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have little problem here. I try to use SqlDataReader to read data from my database. Code is like this:

```
        internal static User GetUser(string login)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DataBaseUtility.ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM BookMenagerDB.dbo.users";
        //where UserLogin like @login
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
            User user = new User();
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            user.Id = (int)sqlDataReader["UserId"];
            user.Login = sqlDataReader["UserLogin"].ToString();
            user.PasswordHash = sqlDataReader["UserPassword"].ToString();
            user.Salt = (byte[])sqlDataReader["UserPasswordSalt"];
            return user;
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GetUser fail");
        }
        conn.Close();
        return new User();
    }
```

I try sql query and I get data but line "user.Id = (int)sqlDataReader["UserId"];" show me there is no data in sqlDataReader. 
I have no idea what the problem is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkX8R.png)

Comment: is it like `//where UserLogin like @login` in your real code? or just comment it in here?

Comment: `sqlDataReader.Read()`. And don't forget to check the return value. And read up on how to use `using`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if `BookMenagerDB.dbo.users` contains many users?

Comment: btw, `where UserLogin = @login`, not LIKE.

Comment: Thx for help and advices, it's working :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `Read()` function on your SqlDataReader to advance the reader to the first or next record from the database. Also you should use disposing to release connection and resources.

```
public User GetUser(string login)
{
    User user = new User();
    const string sql = "SELECT * FROM BookMenagerDB.dbo.users";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DataBaseUtility.ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                user.Id = (int)reader["UserId"];
                user.Login = reader["UserLogin"].ToString();
                user.PasswordHash = reader["UserPassword"].ToString();
                user.Salt = (byte[])reader["UserPasswordSalt"];
            }
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `ExecuteReader()` you should `Read()` to get records:

```
   User user = new User();
   SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if(sqlDataReader.Read())
   {
       user.Id = (int)sqlDataReader["UserId"];
       user.Login = sqlDataReader["UserLogin"].ToString();
       user.PasswordHash = sqlDataReader["UserPassword"].ToString();
       user.Salt = (byte[])sqlDataReader["UserPasswordSalt"];
    }
```